# Is it possible to pass multiple parameters in JQL via the Jira REST API?

Tags: json, response, jira, jql

I would like to filter my JIRA cases by project type and assignee. So my goal is to retrieve JSON response that would only include SUP type projects that are assigned to user 'Tester'.

When I pass only one parameter, it works fine:
https://xxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=UP

However if I write my query with two parameters, it returns the same response (incorrect).
https://xxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=UP&assignee=Tester

What am I doing wrong here, why second link does not filter my cases?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the & with " AND "
Check the docs for Jira REST API search resource